# Tablesorter (mottie fork) / theme bootstrap / headers sorter false => i class still exist

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

My app use jQuery + Tablesorter (mottie fork) to create a server overview table.

I use the Bootstrap theme (`theme.bootstrap.css`) and in the tablesorter init I add

```
theme: "bootstrap"
```

and disable column 0 with

```
headers: { 0: { 
                           sorter: false, 
                           filter: false
                       }
                  },
```

It looks good:

[view of checkbox in header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5jLM.png)

but I have a problem to work with the checkbox. I can only activate it in one pixel right down of the header.

I can see, that the icon for sorting will not show, but the `<i class ..>` is still there.

And this settings overwrite my small header checkbox:

```
<div class="tablesorter-wrapper" style="position:relative;height:100%;width:100%">
   <div class="tablesorter-header-inner"><input name="Marked" value="0" onclick="CheckTable(this,'chkbox_')" type="checkbox"> 
      <i class="tablesorter-icon"></i>
   </div>
</div>
```

Where does this `<i class ...>` come from? What am I doing wrong?

Regards
 Jochen

Tablesorter v2.26.5
jQuery v2.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like it's a bug in the css. I just added the following css definitions to the bootstrap theme (and a few others)

```
.tablesorter-bootstrap .tablesorter-header.sorter-false i.tablesorter-icon {
  display: none;
}
.tablesorter-bootstrap .sorter-false .tablesorter-header-inner {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

If you add them, or update the theme (not released yet) from the master branch.